# How to refresh/Synch View based on a Query with dynamic range?

Tags: view, axapta, synchronized, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a simple *View* with a *Query* , my custom *Query* has a *Dynamically Range*.

In class `SysQueryRangeUtil` I have insered a my custom *public static* method and copy it in my Custom Query.
This range, work well. But I have a problem, when the range condition change, if I want to see the new view(with new selected record) I have to Synch, in AOT my View.

But this operation can't do a simple SystemUser.

There is a way to use a dynamic range in a *View* and not constantly synchronize ?

My dynamic range relates to `curUserId()` when change the user who open the Form/View the view has to change the record displayed. If I want to see de difference I have to synch every time, but for me it's not an usable solution.

[image: DynamicRangeOnQuery]

MyView [image]

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use range on your query, move this logic on form level.

In the `classDeclaration` method of your form declare a variable of type `QueryBuildRange`.

Override `init` method on your form datasource:

```
public void init()
{
    ;

    super();

    queryRange = Table1_ds.query().addRange(MyView_ds.queryBuildDataSource(), AccountNum);
    queryRange.status(RangeStatus::Hidden);
}
```

Override `executeQuery` method on your form datasource:

```
public void executeQuery()
{
    ;

    queryRange.value(filterBycurUserId());

    super();
}
```

Comment: Thank @Aliaksandr Maksimau. But I need to filter with ctrl+G the value. With this way I can't do it, but if I use RangeStatus::Locked or Open I allow to do a free query on form.

Comment: Use `Table1_ds.query().addQueryFilter()` instead of `addRange`. All user ctrl-G are filters, not ranges.

Comment: Thanks @Aliaksandr Maksimau.