# Axapta 2012 - Ax Views and GETDATE()

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I'm trying to make a date range in a view work relative to today. But I'm not find any function to set in the query range to make it dynamic.

Example:
[image]

Creates:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MYCUSTINVOICETABLEVIEW] AS 
SELECT T1.INVOICEID AS INVOICEID,T1.DATAAREAID AS DATAAREAID,T1.PARTITION AS PARTITION,T1.RECID AS RECID 
FROM CUSTINVOICETABLE T1
WHERE (INVOICEDATE<={ts '2017-07-18 00:00:00.000'})
GO
```

But instead of looking relative to *`last synchronization date`*, I want to look compared to *`today`*.

```
SELECT ... FROM CUSTINVOICETABLE T1
WHERE (INVOICEDATE<=GETDATE())
```

Any ideas how I can setup the query ranges for this?

---

Tried so far:

- ..GetDate()
- ..today()
- ..currentDate()
- lessThanDate(0)
- "< GETDATE()"
- < currentSessionDateTime()

According to [How to refresh/Synch View based on a Query with dynamic range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549908/how-to-refresh-synch-view-based-on-a-query-with-dynamic-range), it's not possible (for UserID()). I want to double check if that's the same case for dates. The view is being consumed by a other application on the same box (not an Ax form).

Comment: As far as I know it is the same for dates. You might be able to do some trickery with a computed column because it lets you inject some SQL into the view, but I would not recommend it. Better set the filter everytime the view is used.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't pretty and I still imagine there might be a better way, but here is a solution that I just tested. Obviously there are much better ways of doing this in x++, forms, and reports, but the result of the below can be queried externally from AX and will still return dynamic results.

You have a Query > View > Query > View structure, with the top level view being your consumable view.

The first view has the data you need and a computed date column, populated by the following code to get the dynamic date:

```
public server static str today()
{
    return 'CONVERT (date, GETDATE())';
}
```

You then make a query of that view, and put an extended query range on it to check your field vs the dynamic GETDATE() column. You then have a view built on top of that query that your external application can consume.

In the example below, all field lists are set to dynamic yes. Obviously you would carry the relevant data from the root query all the way up.

[image: Example of what the artifacts would look like]

The example in the picture results in the following view definitions:

```
 CREATE VIEW "DBO".TESTVIEW AS SELECT T1.SALESID AS SALESID,
 T1.RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED AS RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED,
 T1.DATAAREAID AS DATAAREAID,T1.PARTITION AS PARTITION,T1.RECID AS RECID,
 (CAST ((CONVERT (date, GETDATE())) AS DATETIME)) AS CURRENTDATE 
 FROM SALESTABLE T1

 CREATE VIEW "DBO".TESTCONSUMABLEVIEW AS 
 SELECT T1.CURRENTDATE AS CURRENTDATE,T1.RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED AS RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED,
 T1.SALESID AS SALESID,T1.DATAAREAID AS DATAAREAID,T1.PARTITION AS PARTITION,
 T1.RECID AS RECID 
 FROM TESTVIEW T1 WHERE (RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED<CURRENTDATE)
```

Comment: Why did you use a query? Just do it without the query.

Comment: It's a habit of best practice to use queries as views don't support nearly as many options without the query. I like your solution better in this case though as it drastically simplifies it, and you could use the view you created as a root datasource if you needed to say outer join to it.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based off @Spencer Kershaw's answer. So credit for his work, but I want to provide a more succinct answer that doesn't require a query and hopefully is clearer for others trying to accomplish the task.

To accomplish what you want, you need to do 3 things.

1. Create static method to use for computed column
2. Add a computed column to your view
3. Correctly put in the range by using some random field

**1.** Add this method to your view:

```
public server static str today()
{
    return 'CONVERT (date, GETDATE())';
}
```

**2.** Right click on the fields node and click `New>Date Computed Column`. On the properties set `ViewMethod = today`.
[image]

**3.** Add a range. Choose `dataAreaId` for the field (this is arbitrary). Set the `Value` property equal to `("YourComparisonField" < "today")`. The syntax can be important here.

[image]

This produces:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[AAATESTVIEW]
AS
SELECT T1.ADDRESS AS ADDRESS
    ,T1.MODIFIEDDATETIME AS MODIFIEDDATETIME1
    ,T1.RECID AS RECID1
    ,T1.PARTITION AS PARTITION
    ,T1.RECID AS RECID
    ,(CAST((CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) AS DATETIME)) AS TODAY
FROM LOGISTICSPOSTALADDRESS T1
WHERE (N'modifiedDateTime1' < N'today')
GO
```

Comment: It's doing a alphabetical comparision and not on the actual date.

Comment: Try removing the quotes in the `Value` section. I don't think you should need them but for some reason I was getting an error without them.

Comment: Another thing you could do is just make a single computed column that returns `1` or `0` and have it use the `getDate()` in combination with whatever field comparison you want in the same line. This could get a cleaner looking result.